# SQL Server 2017 installation unauthorized error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, installation, authorization

I'm getting the below errors while installing SQL Server on a Windows machine.
I'm using my admin account which has permissions (I’m in Administrations group. Verified here -> Computer management -> Groups)

Does it ring any bells based on the below errors to anyone? Are there any known workarounds. Spent a day without any good solutions. This is a fresh installation btw. The worst part is I can't even uninstall it as it complains about the same unauthorized error.

[image]

[image: SQL]

Comment: Can you add contents of [summary.txt file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-ver15) in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using my admin account which has permissions (I’m in Administrations group ...

Let's get the *obvious* one out of the way ...

Did you run the installer program "*as Administrator*" ?

Just being in the "Administrators" Group *stopped* being enough to "break" your machine somewhere around **Windows Vista**!

To get into an "elevated" security context, wherein you can make changes to your machine, you **must** pass through the [User Account Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/user-account-control-overview) (U.A.C.) "Challenge" by running the installer program "*as Administrator*".